# flush tables - access denied

Tags: mysql

I need to back my database, but when trying to flush the tables before backing up I get this error? What does it mean by `RELOAD` privilege?

Can't find any RELOAD privilege in phpmyadmin!?

```
Error: Access denied; you need the RELOAD privilege for this operation
SQL: FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably you're not running `FLUSH` command using root, but with a limited user.
You need to be granted `RELOAD` privilege to run `FLUSH` command.
Take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_reload) for MySQL privileges.
So (for example) root user should use:

```
GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: it means I can do this instead? `# mysqladmin flush-tables` ?

Comment: @clarkk: if you have `RELOAD` privilege, you can run `mysqladmin` commands that use `FLUSH`... But you have to wait to be granted `RELOAD` privilege...

Comment: where do I put password in your query?

Comment: I assume `GRANT RELOAD ON ...` has to be done from the `root` user in mysql?

Comment: For me, this query resulted in: `ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of DB GRANT and GLOBAL PRIVILEGES`. Answer from @codewaggle worked, though.

Answer (score 27):

To clarify:
RELOAD can only be granted globally, not to a particular database. Need to use `*.*`

```
GRANT RELOAD ON *.* TO 'your_user'@'localhost';
```

From the MySQL docs: [GRANT Syntax - Global Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html#grant-global-privileges)

> The CREATE USER, FILE, PROCESS, RELOAD, REPLICATION CLIENT,
>   REPLICATION SLAVE, SHOW DATABASES, SHUTDOWN, and SUPER privileges are
>   administrative and can only be granted globally.