# mysql table not decreased in size after deleting rows

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I deleted 1M rows from a database table. Surprisingly its size did not decrease. Then I have tried: `FLUSH TABLES;` but whey I ran this statement on phpMyAdmin of my cPanel then I encountered below error:

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RELOAD privilege(s) for this operation
```

How can I decrease my table size and clear its cache?

Comment: possible duplicate of [flush tables - access denied](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972651/flush-tables-access-denied)

Comment: I'm seeking to know are there any methods to solve this problem?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [optimize table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimize-table.html) command

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE <tablename>;
```

Answer (score 4):

In phpMyAdmin, click on the database name to show the tables in the main panel. Then tick the checkbox next to the table name you want to decrease, and in the "With selected" drop-down under the list of tables, choose "Optimize".